# Autowired Environment is null

Tags: java, spring, properties, environment, autowired

I have an issue with connecting environment to my Spring project.
In this class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.pack.offer.*")
@PropertySource("classpath:OfferService.properties")
public class PropertiesUtil {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;



    @Bean
    public String load(String propertyName)
    {
        return environment.getRequiredProperty(propertyName);
    }
}
```

environment always is null.

Comment: Try to use `@Resource` instead of `@Autowired`. See if that helps.

Comment: @PauliusMatulionis, Nope, nothing changed

Comment: @LeYar Is it the only code you have in the `PropertiesUtil` ? Do you have a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` or something like that ?

Comment: And how are you using this `PropertyUtil`...

Comment: Using @Autowired Environment and @Bean PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in same java-based configuration results to environment == null. Implementing EnvironmentAware interface solved this problem. I don`t know if it is a bug.
(Spring 4.2.2)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Autowiring happens later than `load()` is called (for some reason).

A workaround is to implement `EnvironmentAware` and rely on Spring calling `setEnvironment()` method:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.pack.offer.*")
@PropertySource("classpath:OfferService.properties")
public class PropertiesUtil implements EnvironmentAware {
    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(final Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Bean
    public String load(String propertyName)
    {
        return environment.getRequiredProperty(propertyName);
    }
}
```

Comment: In a test environment with Groovy and Spock, Spring is somehow unable to inject the environment no matter how I annotated it (Autowires, Inject, Resource).
Implementing EnvironmentAware as suggested by Alex was the only was to get this working.

Answer (score 16):

Change `@Autowired` for **`@Resource`** (from javax.annotation) and make it `public` e.g.:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
public class HibernateConfigurer {

    @Resource
    public Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("database.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("database.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("database.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("database.password"));
        dataSource.setValidationQuery(env.getProperty("database.validationQuery"));

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

And you must register your configurer class in WebApplicationInitializer this way

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
context.register(ApplicationConfigurer.class); //ApplicationConfigurer imports HibernateConfigurer
```

It's working for me! You may want to check [a test project I made](https://github.com/josuemontano/SHTezt).

Comment: I had to move the @PropertySource from my test to my configuration class..

Answer (score 5):

I solved the same problem with constructor injection:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:my.properties")
public class MyConfig {
    private Environment environment;

    public MyConfig(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment
    }

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
        return new MyBean(environment.getRequiredProperty("srv.name"))
    }
}
```

later, I simplified it to this form (to make properties injected properly):

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:my.properties")
public class MyConfig {
    private String serviceName;

    public MyConfig(Environment ignored) {
        /* No-op */
    }

    @Value("${srv.name}")
    public void setServiceName(String serviceName) {
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
    }

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
        return new MyBean(requireNonNull(serviceName)); // NPE without environment in constructor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Clean and easy: It also can be called in `@PostConstruct` method:

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;

private String appPropertyValue;

@PostConstruct
private void postConstruct() {
    this.appPropertyValue = env.getProperty("myProperty");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put this code inside the class where you are trying to autowire the Environment

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

It solved my issue. Below I give you my class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {   
/**
 * DataSource definition for database connection. Settings are read from the
 * application.properties file (using the env object).
 */
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {

    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("db.driver"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("db.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("db.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

}
```

Comment: no, this doesn't resolve the issue at all