# Trying to convert spring+spring security+hibernate project to spring+spring security+mybatis project

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am trying to convert this http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-remember-me-example-with-hibernate/ into Spring, Spring Security and Mybatis, here is the project structure I have:
[image: Project Structure]

Since I using Java configuration, and I want to get rid the xml file. But when I run the project, I got following issues:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.vincent.configuration.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.vincent.service.UserService com.vincent.service.CustomUserDetailsService.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.vincent.dao.UserDAO com.vincent.service.UserServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.vincent.mapper.UserMapper com.vincent.dao.UserDAOImpl.userMapper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userMapper' defined in file [V:\Programming\SpringMVC\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4\wtpwebapps\SpringSecurityTest\WEB-INF\classes\com\vincent\mapper\UserMapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory': Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in com.vincent.configuration.DatabaseConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in com.vincent.configuration.DatabaseConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

(More and more log after)

I try to fix the problem, but I don't know how to fix....

The full code is in: https://github.com/zhengye1/SpringSecurityTest

Updated:
After I try the solution that llya provided, I got new exception

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.vincent.configuration.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.vincent.service.UserService com.vincent.service.CustomUserDetailsService.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.vincent.dao.UserDAO com.vincent.service.UserServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.vincent.mapper.UserMapper com.vincent.dao.UserDAOImpl.userMapper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userMapper' defined in file [V:\Programming\SpringMVC\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4\wtpwebapps\SpringSecurityTest\WEB-INF\classes\com\vincent\mapper\UserMapper.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ibatis/cursor/Cursor
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Note: If you add `@MapperScan(basePackages="com.vincent.mapper")` you don't need the `mapperScan` bean method. They both does the same job. And how do you start this application?

Comment: @Lucky I drag the project into Tomcat server in Eclipse, and start from Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You have NPE cause environment is not autowired. I don't know exact reason but you can do workaraound as follows ([got from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27801442/1458740)):

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.vincent.configuration" })
@MapperScan(basePackages="com.vincent.mapper")
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class DatabaseConfig implements EnvironmentAware {

    private Environment environment;


    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment arg0) {
        this.environment = arg0;
    }
    //skipped code here
}
```

**UPD**
There is another exception: `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ibatis.cursor.Cursor` because `org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:jar:1.3.0` require `org.mybatis:mybatis:jar:3.4.0`, so upgrade `org.mybatis:mybatis` from `3.1.1` to `3.4.0`.
 There will be one more exception `Failed to parse expression 'isAuthenticated())'` cause there is unnecessary right brace `)` in `'isAuthenticated())'` on `SecurityConfiguration:49`

Comment: I try the way you provided, but seems like still getting the same error

Comment: Try also (in addition to miplementing EnvironmentAware) add `@Import(DatabaseConfig.class)` annotation to OwnWebMVCConfiguration

Comment: That's very strange cause implementing EnvironmentAware fixes NPE from your original question. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you Add "@Service" tag start of your CurrentUserDetailsService class?

```
@Service
public class CurrentUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService
```

Comment: By this code, I actually add the annotation..https://github.com/zhengye1/SpringSecurityTest/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vincent/service/CustomUserDetailsService.java