# Spring Boot @Autowired Environment throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a simple SpringBoot application in which i am using the `Environment.class` to access the properties under `application.properties` file. The `Environment` bean works when it is accessed in the `main` method of the `Application.class`

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.cisco.sdp.cdx.consumers")
public class StreamingConsumerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(StreamingConsumerApplication.class, args);
        Environment env = context.getBean(Environment.class);
        StreamingConsumerFactory factory = context.getBean(StreamingConsumerFactory.class);
        StreamingConsumer streamingConsumer = factory.createStreamingConsumer(StreamType.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("streaming.application.type")));
        streamingConsumer.consume();
    }
}
```

When the same is used in a different class it throws `NullPointerException`. I tried annotating the class with `@Configuration`,`@Component`,`@Repository`,`@Service` annotations but did not work.

I tried `@Autowired` as well as `@Resource` annotations. But, it didn't work.

```
@Component 
public class InventoryStreamingConsumer implements StreamingConsumer {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    @Autowired
    private JavaSparkSessionSingleton sparksession;
    @Autowired
    private StreamingContext _CONTEXT;
    private final Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

    @Override
    public void consume() {
        if(env == null) {
            System.out.println("ENV is NULL");
        }
        System.out.println(env.getRequiredProperty("kafka.brokerlist"));
        kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", env.getRequiredProperty("kafka.brokerlist"));
        Set<String> topics = Collections.singleton(env.getRequiredProperty("kafka.topic"));

    // Unrelated code.
}
```

I tried following the answers provided in the below questions

[Spring Boot - Environment @Autowired throws NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454289/spring-boot-environment-autowired-throws-nullpointerexception)

[Autowired Environment is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421092/autowired-environment-is-null)

I am looking for suggestions on solving the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@Configuration` annotation is misused here for `InventoryStreamingConsumer`. Try `@Component`, `@Repository` or `@Service`.

---

UPDATE

Another misuse is

```
StreamingConsumer streamingConsumer = factory.createStreamingConsumer(StreamType.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("streaming.application.type")));
```

`@Autowired` or `@Resource` can only work in `bean` created by `Spring`. the `streamingConsumer` created by your `StreamingConsumerFactory factory` cannot use `@Autowired` for injection of its properties.

You should create an `@Configuration` class, to tell `Spring` to create `streamingConsumer` from your factory. Like this

```
@Configuration
public class ConsumerCreator {

    @Autowired
    StreamingConsumerFactory factory;

    @Bean
    public StreamingConsumer streamingConsumer() {
        return factory.createStreamingConsumer(StreamType.valueOf(env.getRequiredProperty("streaming.application.type")));
    }
}
```

And use no annotation for `InventoryStreamingConsumer`, meanwhile use

```
        StreamingConsumer streamingConsumer = context.getBean(StreamingConsumer.class);
```

in your `StreamingConsumerApplication.main()` method instead to retrieve `streamingConsumer`

Answer (score 1):

First, please annotate the main class with only `@SpringBootApplication`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StreamingConsumerApplication {
}
```

`@ComponentScan` is required if your packages are not within the same structure as main class with main class being outside the sub-package and inside parent package with every other class in the same or some sub-package of parent package.

Second, Please create a Configuration class and annotate it with `@Configuration` separately and define a `@Bean` there for `StreamingConsumer streamingConsumer` and than it can be `@Autowired` or injected in the `InventoryStreamingConsumer` class.

Third, where is the `@Bean` for **JavaSparkSessionSingleton** defined? Are you sure it can be AutoConfigured for injection

Fourth, `InventoryStreamingConsumer` can be a `@Component`, injecting `Environment` with `@Autowiring` will work once the above things are sorted.

Also, recommending to change your class to this for the sake depending on how `consume()` method is used.

```
@Component 
public class InventoryStreamingConsumer implements StreamingConsumer {

private final Environment env;

private final JavaSparkSessionSingleton sparksession;

private final StreamingContext _CONTEXT;

private final Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

@Autowired
public InventoryStreamingConsumer(Environment env, JavaSparkSessionSingleton sparkSession, StreamingContext context) {
    this.env = env;
    this.sparksession = sparkSession;
    this._CONTEXT = context;
}

@Override
public void consume() {
    if(env == null) {
        System.out.println("ENV is NULL");
    }
    System.out.println(env.getRequiredProperty("kafka.brokerlist"));
    kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", env.getRequiredProperty("kafka.brokerlist"));
    Set<String> topics = Collections.singleton(env.getRequiredProperty("kafka.topic"));

// Unrelated code.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue but read the properties from different file and different location like **common/jdbc.properties**. I solved this issue by doing this:

```
import org.springframework.context.EnvironmentAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:common/jdbc.properties"})
public class ExternalConfig implements EnvironmentAware {

private Environment environment;

public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
    this.environment = environment;
}

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}

public String getJdbcUrl() {
    return environment.getProperty("jdbc.url");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
```

on InventoryStreamingConsumer class

This is how am using it

```
@Configuration 
@ComponentScan({ "com.spring.config" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class HibernateConfiguration {


    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));
        return dataSource;
    }
```