# How to fix NPE in hibernate config?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

@Autowired Environment env - always null.This is my HibernateConf.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:hibernate.properties" })
public class HibernateConf{

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        final LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"Enteties"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")));
        dataSource.setUrl(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tutorialdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true")));
        dataSource.setUsername(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("root")));
        dataSource.setPassword(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("9339")));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
        final HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("create-drop"));
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"));

        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

So the main problem it is that this `@Autowired private Environment env;` always NPE but I don't know why because every example of this config class is the same as mine. How can I fix it?

Comment: Your properties aren't properties, but rather the actual value.

Comment: what you mean?what i shoud to do?

Comment: Please see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421092/autowired-environment-is-null

Comment: anyway i need to inject my environment, where i need to do it?

Comment: the class you are using to import the properties from Environment

Comment: you need to do two things. First, implement the EnvironmentAware to the class and then override the setEnvironment() method and then you can load/fetch the properties from environment

Comment: i mean public void setEnvironment(final Environment environment)  where i need to inject this environment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: That link you added is about NPE at all my problem is different.

Comment: `env.getProperty("9339")` I highly doubt that `9339` is the name of a property. Also properties cannot be null so doing a `Preconditions.checkNotNull` isn't needed.

Comment: yep you right. I want to explain that you need use it without  env.getProperty.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author to move it from the question to the answer space)*.

I found the solution to this problem. First you need to remove `@Autowired private Environment env;` and second `dataSource.setPassword("9339")` use it just with String parameters.

Thirdly, you need to have not 5.0...mysql-connector not 4.0... but this one:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>8.0.17</version>
</dependency>
```