# Spring environment.getActiveProfiles(); is always null

Tags: spring, environment-variables, spring-profiles

I have page in xhtml, I want to not render this page on production so I wrapped all elements on page with panel

```
<p:panel id="main" rendered="#{swaggerBean.activeProfiles}" >
```

SwaggerBean.class:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
@Data
public class SwaggerBean{

   @Autowired
   Environment environment;


   public boolean getActiveProfiles() {
       String[] activeProfiles = environment.getActiveProfiles();
       for (String activeProfile : activeProfiles) {
           if (activeProfile.contains("prod"))
               return true;
       }
       return false;
  }
}
```

After I try to enter to my page I have null pointer exception on line:

```
String[] activeProfiles = environment.getActiveProfiles();
```

I also tried to inject Environment by @ManagedProperty, but result is the same

```
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{environment}")
    private Environment environment;
```

Do You know how to avoid this null pointer on my @ManagedBean?
I tried solution with EnvironmentAware  from [Autowired Environment is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421092/autowired-environment-is-null), but still there's NPE, or maybe there's better way to disable my page on production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate SwaggerBean with @Component rather than @ManagedBean